# MongoDB - Large export/import questions

Tags: database, mongodb, migration

We're moving an application that uses MongoDB as it's local DB from an older version of the app and server OS to a new server that is fully updated.  OS, App, and MongoDB are all getting updates.  Server is built and running, and the standard "export MongoDB, migrate data, import dump files into new MongoDB" works fine.

My problem is that the entire process, including waiting for the new DB to rebuild indexes, takes like 3.5 hours or so.  While I can accept this, I REALLY want to minimize my downtime window since this app is used to directly support external customers.  Obviously, downtime needs to be minimized.  So I want to speed this process up if possible.

I've thought of ways to speed up the transfer between the boxes, use SSD disk, etc, but I had another thought.  First, know that I'm a Linux Engineer, NOT a DBA, and not overly familiar w/ MongoDB.  So please excuse my ignorance....

I'm wondering if I can snapshot the disk MongoDB stores it's data on (yes, it's on a Virtual server), mount that snapshot on the new server, and do a direct import/add of the data.  IE: skip the dump/restore process altogether, and just do a straight import/add of the raw data?  Does MongoDB have this ability?

Comment: If the new server will be the same version of MongoDB or 1 version higher, then yes.  If you attempt that method when upgrading from say MongoDB 3.2 to MongoDB 4.0, it may or may not even complete, and may or may not be able to read all of the data.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided on the old "tried and true" dump/restore process.  Took a little longer, but why fix what wasn't broken?

Thanks!